# How can I count the number of rows in a dataframe that differ from one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I know it isn't something one should do here, though I don't know how otherwise I could ask that question.

```
data_train = pd.DataFrame({"buying": [0,1,0,1,0,0,0], "maint":[0,1,0,1,0,0,0], "doors": [0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
                          "persons": [0,1,0,1,0,0,0], "lug_boot":[0,1,0,1,0,0,0], "safety": [0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
                          "rating" : [1,1,2,1,3,4,5] })


data_train = data_train.groupby(["buying", "maint", "doors", "persons", "lug_boot", "safety"]) \
.agg({"buying": "count", "maint": "nunique"})#.query("buying>1")["maint"].sum()
```

My objective is to count how many rows have the same first predictors (buying, maint, etc.), but different ratings.

---

My attempt was to grouby the first columns, and then count the number of differrent ratings I get, it would be great.

An important assumption is, if two rows are identical, they have been erased beforehand. So one can find rows that differ by the ratings, but no identical rows.

Here in my example, row 1 and 3 are identical, thus one is erased and there is no problem. However, for the others, they differ by ratings, so there is a problem and I should get as a return 5, because there is 5 same predictors rows that differ by their ratings.

Is it understandable?

Comment: rows `0,2` and `3` have the same first column, but different last column. So 3 rows and result 3?

Comment: you're right ^^', the good answer has been corrected.

Comment: Could you provide more context? I mean, assume in the last column the value 2 appears twice under group "A". How would you want to count that. not at all, with 1? I'm not really sure if that problem is really well posed and your example set, seems to be very small. What about the "B" group. It could contribute 1 as well ...

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I added a few lines. My request should be more understand now :) the example is good I think. Can you please edit your answer to also include x2 as a factor of similarity between lines ?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 No sorry... I got confused by myself ... now it should be right. Apologies again.

Comment: no it shouldn't give 4. Or if so, I don't understand the logic

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 You're right. One of my assumption was that we don't have any duplicate in the lines. So the result is 2. My first examples were aweful. It wasn't clear at all, I apologise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be done with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"x1": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"], "x2":[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3], "x3": [0,1,0,1,0,0,0]})
df.groupby(["x1", "x2"]).agg({'x1':"count", "x3":"nunique"}).query("x1 >1")["x3"].sum()
```

gives

```
2
```

We are gathering the number of rows per group (it's enough to aggregate w.r.t `x1`) and the number of different values for the last column. We want to have at least two rows per group, right? Then we just sum the results after the subquery, i.e. filtering the groups with at least two entries.

Comment: if there is multiple columns "x1", then i 'm replacing "x1" by ["x1","x2"] right ?

Comment: only if `"x2"` is not your last column, but yes

Comment: Sorry, so what's the answer? Are you waiting for any information from my side ?

Comment: I updated the answer according to the new column. Nevertheless, the question is not very specific

Comment: What do you mean, I thought you would also have to put "x2 > 1". In the question I wrote "the first columnS". Can you tell me what's not specific ? I really don't know what isn't clear :'( I thought it is one of the best questions I asked so far.

Comment: I commented on that in my answer. The conditions for the desired output are just not precisely stated

Comment: Please check the new version ? Perhaps it's clearer. I can't erase the question to ask again.

Comment: where do yo now fail in applying my answer? I think it's clearer now. Also that you mentioned that duplicate rows are removed helps a lot.

Comment: I wrote in the new post how I tried to apply your answer and it doesn't work. I don't get 5 but 2

Comment: you shouldn't use `maint` but `rating`. So `maint` is essentially `x2` and `x3` is `rating` after proper generalization of course.

Answer (score 2):

As things have been changed too much and new information is available:

A solution is just:

```
nuniques = data_train.groupby(data_train.columns[:-1].tolist())['rating'].nunique()
```

Here you see the unique ratings per row (or groups of row). Now if `nunique == 1` and since we are not having duplicates, we can just filter on the groups with `nunique>1`.
Thus

```
nuniques[nuniques>1].sum()
5
```